# How To implement Quartz Scheduler in server side? What all are the steps i want to do?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

```
public static void setupSchedule() {
    try {
        SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler scheduler = sf.getScheduler();
        JobDetail job = newJob(Reader.class).withIdentity("job1", "group1").build();
        String Frequency = Props.getProps().getProperty("BIRTHDAYFREQUENCY");
        CronTrigger ct = newTrigger().withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
            .withSchedule(cronSchedule(Frequency)).build();

        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, ct);

    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question or are you looking for a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking to implement quartz scheduler in web application then answer is yes.
All you have to do put all scheduler configuration in `servlet` init method. Like you have done it your question. Init method will be called only once on start-up of application or on first request. So all the configuration and scheduler time will be set at that time. Make sure to include all the quartz dependencies.

```
private Scheduler scheduler ;
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException 
    {
JobKey jobKeyA = new JobKey("jobA", "group1");
        JobDetail jobA = JobBuilder.newJob(CallJob.class)
        .withIdentity(jobKeyA).build();
        //jobA.getJobDataMap().put("queue_setup", queue_setup);
        Trigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder
        .newTrigger()
        .withIdentity("triggerJobA", "group1")
        .withSchedule(
                SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                .withIntervalInMinutes(1).repeatForever()).build();
//runs every minute
scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
scheduler.start();
scheduler.scheduleJob(jobA, trigger1);

}

Job class
public class CallJob implements Job {
@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException 
    {
System.out.println("Yes job is running");
}
}
```